# TensorFlow Lite: toco_convert for arbitrary sized input tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Looking at converting my TensorFlow model to the Flatbuf format (`.tflite`).

However, my model allows input of arbitrary size, i.e. you can classify one item, or N items at once.  When I try to convert, it throws an error since one of my input/output devices is of type `NoneType`.

Think of something like the [TensorFlow MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/get_started/mnist/pros), where in the computation graph, our input `x` is of shape `[None, 784]`.

From the [tflite dev guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/mobile/tflite/devguide), you can convert your model to FlatBuf like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.placeholder(name="img", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 64, 64, 3))
val = img + tf.constant([1., 2., 3.]) + tf.constant([1., 4., 4.])
out = tf.identity(val, name="out")

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tflite_model = tf.contrib.lite.toco_convert(sess.graph_def, [img], [out])
  open("converteds_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

However, this does not work for me.  A MWE could be:

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.placeholder(name="inputs", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
out = tf.identity(inputs, name="out")


with tf.Session() as sess:
  tflite_model = tf.contrib.lite.toco_convert(sess.graph_def, [img], [out])
  open("converteds_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Error: `TypeError: __int__ returned non-int (type NoneType)`

Looking at the  [tf.contrib.lite.toco_convert](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lite/toco_convert)  docs, we have "input_tensors: List of input tensors. Type and shape are computed using foo.get_shape() and foo.dtype.".  So that's where our failure likely is.  But I'm not sure if there's an argument I should be using or something that would allow me to export a model like this

Comment: It may be that if your model doesn't have fully shape information you may need to specify it with input_shapes=None, that being said if you export to a SavedModel and provide that to tflite_convert you may have more look since that tooling has been completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is already resolved in the newest converter code. You can pass an input tensor where the 1st dimension is `None` (the 1st dimension is usually batch), and the converter will handle it correctly.

BTW, before invoking the interpreter, you can call `interpreter.resize_tensor_input` to change the batch size.

Comment: hi , late reply but I am facing the same problem and I can't solve it , can you provide the line of code to solve the problem? how to pass an input with that shape [None, None, None, 3] ?